# Class and constructor C++ - errors & warnings C2146, C4430

Tags: c++

I am trying to access `class MyMainClass` from within other classes. I want to create new instance of classes `FILE_` and `MyParser` and to pass pointer to the `MyMainClass` instance. But I am getting some errors.

Definitions.h:

```
#ifndef DESTINATION_CONST
#define DESTINATION_CONST
class MyMainClass;
#endif
```

MyParser.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
class MyParser{
private:
    PMainInstance * globalInstance;
public:
    MyParser(  MyMainClass * globInst ){
    PMainInstance = globInst;
    }
        void static ParseArgs(int argc, char* argv[]){}
};
```

File.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

FILE_::FILE_( MyMainClass * globInst){
    PMainInstance = globInst;
};
```

main class global.h:

```
class MyMainClass{
    private:    
    MyParser JustPars( MyMainClass );
        FILE_ File( MyMainClass );
};
```

Now I get error on the last lines when using default constructor:

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'JustPars'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
warnning C4183: 'JustPars': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
```

These are errors to the two lines:

```
MyParser JustPars ...
FILE_ File ...
```

What does mean these errors and warnings and how to fix the errors?

Comment: Cheezeburgerz like `PMainInstance = globInst` are wrong. You are trying to assign a variable to a type. You can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Each class definition must end with a semicolon.  For example:

```
class Foo {};
```

Comment: Typo (I have semicolons in the code - but I have forgot to write it when I have shorten the code of class)

Answer (score 0):

Put a semicolon after each class definition:

```
class MyParser {
    //... body
};
 ^
```

Then initialize the members of a class in the constructor initialization list:

```
class MyMainClass{
    private:    
    MyParser JustPars;
    FILE_ File;
    public:
         MyMainClass( MyMainClass* globInst) : JustPars( globInst ),
                                               File( globInst)
                                               {}
}
```

Comment: Really? `JustPars(MyMainClass)`

Comment: Do you mean to do this with the header of MyMainClass? Because the definition (.cpp) start like this ... MyMainClass::MyMainClass(int argc, char* argv[]){ ...

Comment: yes, put this in .h as this is the definition of class

Comment: As far as I know there should no be definitions {} in header files. I always write without {}. I always was used to write like this: functionName(args..); for constructor ... or returnType functionName(args..); IMHO, adding {} would break the Rule of One. But I added it without {} to the header and with {... to the .cpp . But even that I checked carefully if all classes definitions are ended with ; so still it print s error like something is not ended with ";"

Comment: you lack ";" still somewhere or maybe something is not declared

Comment: I found it: in the parser class cpp see this: `private:
    PMainInstance * globalInstance; // this causes the problem with ';'` When I commented it and rest of the code on all headers and cpp files so it compiled successfully. Should be `#include "stdafx.h"
class CLParser{
private:
 MyMainClass * globalInstance;`